# I can't pass parameters to foreach loop while implementing Structured Streaming + Kafka in Spark SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, nullpointerexception

I followed the instructions at [Structured Streaming + Kafka](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#deploying) and built a program that receives data streams sent from **kafka** as input, when I receive the data stream I want to pass it to **SparkSession** variable to do some query work with Spark SQL, so I extend the ForeachWriter class again as follows:

```
package stream;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import dataservices.OrderDataServices;
import models.SuccessEvent;

public class MapEventWriter extends ForeachWriter<String>{
private SparkSession spark;

public MapEventWriter(SparkSession spark) {
    this.spark = spark;
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void close(Throwable errorOrNull) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public boolean open(long partitionId, long epochId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public void process(String input) {     
    OrderDataServices services = new OrderDataServices(this.spark);
}
}
```

however in the process function, if I use **spark** variable, the program gives an error, the program passes in my spark as follows:

```
package demo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import dataservices.OrderDataServices;
import models.MapperEvent;
import models.OrderEvent;
import models.SuccessEvent;
import stream.MapEventWriter;
import stream.MapEventWriter1;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TimeoutException, StreamingQueryException, ParseException, IOException {
        try (SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Read kafka").getOrCreate()) {
            Dataset<String> data = spark
                    .readStream()
                    .format("kafka")
                    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                    .option("subscribe", "tiki-1")
                    .load()
                    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
                    .as(Encoders.STRING());
            
            MapEventWriter eventWriter = new MapEventWriter(spark);
            
            StreamingQuery query = data
                    .writeStream()
                    .foreach(eventWriter)
                    .start();
            
            query.awaitTermination();
            
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

The error is **NullPointerException** at the **spark** call location, that is, no spark variable is initialized.
Hope anyone can help me, I really appreciate it.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.<init>(DataFrameReader.scala:998)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.read(SparkSession.scala:655)
    at dataservices.OrderDataServices.<init>(OrderDataServices.java:18)
    at stream.MapEventWriter.process(MapEventWriter.java:38)
    at stream.MapEventWriter.process(MapEventWriter.java:15)
```

Comment: I don't think you should be passing though the Spark object. Especially because it should only be used at the driver, not the executor running the ForEach. You can only use String input parameter from the process method (which you're ignoring)... Use map function if you need to run more methods on the Dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do some query work with Spark SQL

You wouldn't use a ForEachWriter for that

```
.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
          .as(Encoders.STRING());  // or parse your JSON here using a schema 

data.select(...)  // or move this to a method / class that takes the Dataset as a parameter

// await termination
```